# Именительный и творительный падежи: "бросил камень" и "бросил камнем"

Tags: стилистика, грамматика, семантика

Здравствуйте! Вопрос следующий:
почему можно сказать "бросил камнем в мужика" и "бросил камень в мужика" и оба варианта будут правильными?

Answer (score 1):

> почему можно сказать "бросил камнем..." и "бросил камень..." и оба
> варианта будут правильными?

Почему? Так сложилось в языке. Глагол ***бросить***  в русском языке управляет и винительным, и творительным падежом.

***Из "Словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка" под ред. Денисова и Морковкина***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получается, что глагол "бросать" является непереходным, когда управляет творительным, да?

Comment: Ну почему же? Остаётся переходным. Способен глагол  управлять сущ. в вин. падеже без предлога и имеет словоформы действ. и страд. залогов -- значит переходный. Способность же иметь, кроме прямого, ещё и косвенные дополнения не выводит глагол из состава переходных.